# Consume C# REST service with Java client

Tags: java, c#, wcf-rest

I have following C# REST service definition

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "books/{isbn}")]
void CreateBook(string isbn, Book book);
```

I want to consume this service from a Java client.

```
    String detail = "<Book><Autor>" + autor + "</Autor><ISBN>" + isbn + "</ISBN><Jahr>" + jahr + "</Jahr><Titel>" + titel + "</Titel></Book>";
    URL urlP = new URL("http://localhost:18015/BookRestService.svc/books/" + isbn);
    HttpURLConnection connectionP = (HttpURLConnection) urlP.openConnection();
    connectionP.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
    connectionP.setConnectTimeout(15*1000);
    connectionP.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connectionP.setDoOutput(true);
    connectionP.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml"); 
    connectionP.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString( detail.length() )); 
    OutputStream os = connectionP.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
    pw.println(detail);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    int retc = connectionP.getResponseCode();
    connectionP.disconnect();
```

The service returns 400 to my Java client. The same service works fine when called from a C# client.

Comment: A 400 means a bad request - but usually a server will tell you what's bad about it (malformed XML, missing header, etc).  So it would be great to see the status line and the body content of the response.  Also, using an actual rest client might help a bit in undersanding the issue. (spring rest template, cxf, ...)

Comment: To complete @JoeriHendrickx answer, I would say that you have different response from both clients for a simple reason : you don't send the same requests. You can use tools, like https://requestb.in/, to analyze the http request actually sent from both clients and see what's different. You also can post the results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that way you write to the stream may be the reason, try this:

```java
connectionP.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connectionP.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes(detail);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your server code you use `UriTemplate = "books/{isbn}` as URI template, but your client code specifies the URI as `"http://localhost:18015/BookRestService.svc/booksplain/" + isbn`.

Maybe you only need to change the URI in Java code to reflect the server URI, for example "books" instead of "booksplain" `"http://localhost:18015/BookRestService.svc/books/" + isbn`.

Also, if you are interested in making your code cleaner and more concise, consider using [Spring RestTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) for making REST API calls.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to books vs booksplain. This was a typo. I actually tried it with books and it does not work.